# CSS Navigation menu slides to right when hovering

Tags: css, menu, hover

I have a navigation menu and I wanted to have a dropdown menu for subpages. I created it and everything is ok except that the pages links in the top menu slide over to the right when the dropdown shows when I hover the page link with subpages.
What is it that I am missing here?
Thanks for the help in advance.

---

Here is the jsfiddle:
jsfiddle.net/AC8XK/

What I have is not 100% like that, since there is a lot missing, but it shows exactly the problem I mentioned.

---

**I managed to get the menu working properly. The solution to the initial problem was, as mike said, changing the dropdown *ul position* from *relative* to *absolute*.**

**As for the positioning of the dropdown, I solved the problem by using *padding-top* instead of *top* or *margin-top*.**

**Thanks to everyone that tried to help.**

Comment: You need to show some code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Post some code as an example. I have a hunch that you're displaying the list items (assuming you're using a list for navigation) incorrectly, so the top-level items have to move to make horizontal room for the sub-items, even if they wouldn't overlap normally

Comment: +1 on posting code or better yet, do a jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you supplied in jsfiddle was..well...a bit of a mess. I had to strip a lot of it down and generate some base formatting for the dropdown. I will comment the important bits, but it should be more or less copy & paste. The code is **solely** the layout text for the menu - no visual or positional styling stuff.

Key Concepts: 1 - Set your LIs to `width:auto` and the li>ul to `position: absolute;width:100%`. This allows positioning and makes sure the individual `ul ul li`s are on separate lines.
2- You had the `display:none` and `display:block` correct. Alternatively, you can use off-the-screen positioning for the same purpose.
3- Remember to do `ul ul {position:absolute;}` to allow positioning of the submenus relative to the parent `li`!

HTML:

```
<div class="greenbar">
<nav>
    <ul id="menu-navigation-menu" class="navigation">
        <li id="menu-item-107" class="menu-item"><a href="#">About</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Just another link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-106" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Another link again</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-105" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}
nav ul li {float: left;}
nav ul li a { display: block; text-decoration: none;}
nav ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: auto;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul { display: block;}
nav ul ul li { width: 100%;}
```

Comment: That should be the problem. I had absolute position but the dropdown would show somewhere above the navigation menu (the menu is not right in the top) and so I changed it to relative, which allowed for the dropdown to show below the page link.
So, I have to change it back to absolute, but how do I make it show below the link then? Using margin?

Comment: I changed it to absolute and managed to place it where I wanted, but now I can't hover the dropdown, because it disappears when I'm trying to hover it. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: I'm unsure what the issue is. I added `position: absolute;` to your jsfiddle, and tweaked the positioning of the ul ul and it worked fine.

Perhaps you could add the actual code in the original question?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Check the updated fiddle: jsfiddle.net/AC8XK/1/
I changed the position to absolute and tweaked the position to my liking. When you hover the About link and try to go to the dropdown, it disappears.
PS: I added margin-top: 5px; there to make it look better. In the site it has a grey bar there, so it's about the same.

Comment: @AlexAlexandre are you wanting to do this strictly with javascript or can you use jquery?

Comment: Hey ObieMD5, thanks for taking a look. This is a pure css menu, no javascript needed at all. But I already solved the problem, so no further help needed. Thanks again.