# How do I control the spacing between my child links in my CSS driven menu dropdown?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, spacing

This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756114/css-navigation-menu-slides-to-right-when-hovering) has already been great in helping me set my nav bar. But now, my child links have large spaces between and do not line up with the parent links.

My site can be seen [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/189845951/cuddle%20critters%20with%20menu%20dropdown/html/index%20with%20menu%20dropdown.html)

Any ideas on how to align my child links (Los Angeles, San Diego Honolulu...etc.) with the parent link (Location)? Also, how do I reduce the space between the child links (Los Angeles, San Diego, Honolulu...)?

This is my CSS for quicker reference.

```
#mainNav {
/*font-size: 1.0em;    doesn't seem to do anything*/
/*height: 20px;      doesn't seem to do anything*/
margin-top: -10px;
position: absolute;
right: 5%;
top: 40%;
}
/*-------------------------------*/
/*----------Below is CSS for List of Parent Links---------------------*/
#mainNav ul {                               
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}
/*----------Below is CSS for List of Location Links---------------------*/
#mainNav ul ul{
list-style: none;
display: none;
}
/*----------Below is CSS for List of Location---------------------*/
#mainNav ul li {float: left;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0 0 0 25px;
padding-top: 0;
float: left;
width: auto;
list-style: none outside none;
font-size: 0.90em;
text-transform: uppercase;}

#mainNav ul li a {display: block; text-decoration: none;}

#mainNav ul ul {
display: none; /*if this is block, it causes all the sub links to show at once!*/
position: absolute;
width: auto;
top: 35%;
}

#mainNav ul li:hover > ul { display: block;}
#mainNav ul ul li {width: 100%;}

#mainNav li li {
float: none;
width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code ended up doing it for me. I think you copied and pasted wrong Rohit!

```
li{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
/*width: 150px;*/
max-width: auto;
}

ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: center;

padding: 10px; /*needed for spacing between LOCATIONS and LOS ANGELES*/
}

ul li ul li a{
padding-top: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
float: left;
font-weight:bold;
}

ul ul{
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
}

#mainNav ul li:hover ul{
visibility: visible;
padding: 0;
}

ul li ul li{
display: block;
}
```

Click here for the [latest](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/189845951/cuddle%20critters%20with%20menu%20dropdown/html/index%20with%20menu%20dropdown.html).

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this css**

```
#mainNav ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: auto;
top: 13px;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: normal;
}
#mainNav ul ul li {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: red;
margin-top: 2px;
}


#mainNav ul li{}

#mainNav ul li > ul > li a {
height: auto;
line-height: 21px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
}
```

**Result images**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you copied the right CSS? Also, could you briefly highlight what you changed? [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/Lk7Onsc)